# header image left:0 - float with browser resize - but stop after aligned with page div element

Tags: resize, alignment, css-float, justify

I have a question that I don't particularly know how to phrase properly so apologies in advance for lack of proper terminology.  What I'm attempting to do is have a header image aligned left - left:0px; - with position:absolute; so that when the page loads on different sized screens it'll always be stuck to the left side of the browser window.  But at the same time I want the header image to stop when it's loaded on a larger sized screen when it's aligned left with the page (if this makes sense).  The page is below:

http://tinyurl.com/d2zttye

I want the BREAKWATER image to float with the page as it resizes but stop when it meets the background image below it (the #page div). So when loading in windows that are greater than the size of the background image (1592px) it won't float farther left.  As of now it doesn't float with the page size and gets cut off on smaller screens.

Hopefully this makes sense and let me know if I need to clarify anything.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!  By using @media screen I was able to define how the header would position on the page when the browser window is smaller than 1592px and larger than 1593px.  #bwheader is the div and when the window is smaller than 1592px it floats left with the browser with a 10px left padding.  When the window is larger than 1593px it then remains fixed (but using the position:absolute and centering the div using negative margins and 50% left).  Hope this helps anyone that needs it!

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1592px) 
 {
    #bwheader{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    height:74px;
    float:left;
    padding-left:10px;
 }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1593px) 
 {
    #bwheader{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    width:1592px;
    margin-left:-796px;
    left:50%;
    height:74px;
 }
}
```